# How to replace text in object value from input?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I'm getting JSON from backend. User has to edit templates, add his data and send it back to server. How is it possible to edit object value from input. How to connect each variables(name, company, job) in object to input field. Do I need to use regex or there is any other way? This just a piece of whole JSON.

```
templates: {
        {
          message_content:
            "Hello {{name}}, My name is Ann, from {{company}}",
        },
        {
          message_content: "Are you looking for job as a {{job}}?",
        },
```

}

Comment: is this a static data ?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan yes, but in braces should update dynamically

Comment: If the data will be static why don't you remake it and put that string into object?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan User has to see what is changing . I'm directly displaying content message like this <div>{templates.message_content}</div>. How I supposed to remake it?

Answer (score 1):

u probably use regexp to achieve this for example

```
var message= template.message_content;
var finalVal = null;
        var r = message.match(/\{[\w]+\}/g);
        r && r.forEach((state) => {
            var regex = new RegExp(state, 'g')
            var stateItem = state.split(/{|}/g)[1]
            finalVal = message.replace(regex, this.state.obj[stateItem])
        })
```

**Note:** RegExp matches for single curly braces only bcz react uses single curly braces if u want to match for double curly braces changes reg exp match pattern accordingly